# How to stop google from recognizing me?

Tags: gmail

I've done everything to make myself anynomous but Google still recognizes me.

What I am trying to do is create multiple Gmail accounts. I can only create one account and if I try second time, it asks me to verify mobile number, which I cannot skip.

Now, I have tried using VPN (on various servers) and clearing all browser data. So, to Gmail I should be a new user everytime I do this and it shouldn't ask for my phone number (it doesn't ask for the first time). What happens instead is Google always knows that I've already created an account and asks me to verify my mobile number.

What methods do Google use to track me? Is there a way out of this?

Comment: Hi Asad Ali, Stack Overflow is a site for programming questions. You might have better luck asking your question on a different Stack Exchange site like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'll delete this question.